# How the divider will show after 5th box/row?

Tags: php

**I want to add or show a divider/dotted underline after 5th box/row only once below is my php code, now it shows after every box/row**

```
<div class="categories-holder">
<?php if ($categories) { ?>
<?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
<div class="box-c">
<div class="bottom">
<div class="top">
<ul class="category">
<li><img src="<?php echo $base; ?>image/<?php echo $category['image']; ?>" width="30" height="30" alt=" " class="icon" /><a href="#" class="link"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></li>
</ul>
<div class="clr"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php if (count($categories) > '5') { ?>
<div class="divider"></div>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Use a counter and modulo.

Answer (score 1):

You can add some counter and increment it in each loop and than use modulo like:

```
 $counter = 0;
 if ($counter % 5 == 0) { 
   ...Display divider...
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much